# I need to relate the some images to their outputs but the images are messy Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, jupyter-notebook, output

So I have one dataset of 10000 outputs which have the elements ("id","letter") and one with 10000 images but they are not sorted. I need to relate my outputs with the images.

--> The output dataset is like this:

id lletra

0      W

1      t

2      U

3      q

4      S

...

--> The names of the images in the file are like : "train_image_00001.png", ..., "train_image_09999.png"

I did the following code to import the images (it works well, but I don't know if I have to modify it):

```
dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images_train')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

idata_train = []
directories = []
dircount = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0

print("leyendo imagenes de ",imgpath)

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            cant=cant+1
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = plt.imread(filepath)
            idata_train.append(image)
            b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
            print (b, end="\r")
            if prevRoot !=root:
                print(root, cant)
                prevRoot=root
                directories.append(root)
                dircount.append(cant)
                cant=0
dircount.append(cant)

dircount = dircount[1:]
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
print("Imagenes en cada directorio", dircount)
print('suma Total de imagenes en subdirs:',sum(dircount))
```

Comment: What is your question please? Are you hoping to rename some existing files? Or change your program to create differently named output files? Or do something else?

Comment: I mean, I need to do a classification image model, and for that I have a .cvs where i have an id and a the the letter of the image, and then a have a folder with all the images. i exported the .cvs and the images but I don't know how to join them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What is `W`? What is `t`? How is `W` related to `train_image_00001.png`?

Comment: the id is the identifier, so if "id" = 0, it should be identified  with "train_image_00001.png" and so, "train_image_00001.png" should be a picture of the letter "W".